# Connector/Net reference not found

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, mysql-connector

I'm getting this error message

```
BC30002: Type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' is not defined.
```

However, there is a MySql.Data.dll file within Bin and there is a reference to it in web.config. It is imported in the aspx.vb file too.

I should add that when running locally through Visual Studio this application works fine - all I've done is copied the files to a remote server and this message comes up
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Mysql Connector** you should reference to the **same version of mysql connector dll file** which is installed on remote computer.